# Get the list of geopoints on a string array from a KML file

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

Hi i got a KML file with driving directions between two points and i want to just parse the geopoints in there to a string array so i can use them.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use XML Pull Parser or Document Builder to decode the KML file to get all geo points.

The link below provides all information to decode the KML file. Initially the information available at below link seem to be very difficult to understand. But if you pay liitle concentration you will get it easily.

[Android driving direction route path](http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html)

I hope you will understand this and makes useful.